# FastApi UploadFile and Data

Tags: python, fastapi

I have a fastapi project. I want to one of endpoints to UploadFile and post some data. How can i do it ?

For example:

```
@app.post("/example")
async def example(image: UploadFile, transaction_id: str, organization_id: str):
```

I need to BaseModel to do it. I try;

```
class Example(BaseModel):
    image: UploadFile = File()
    transaction_id: str = None
    organization_id: str = None
```

But i am getting error with decode utf8.

I am waiting your valuable answers. :)

I expect upload file and some data with using basemodel

Comment: you need to decide how do you want to store files in your project, in db or in filesystem and store path in model instead of storing whole file

Comment: I need to store filesystem

Comment: You can't use a JSON body together with UploadFile, so you'll have to either include the values as query arguments (as you've done), as Form arguments as shown in the answer below, or as Path values.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`UploadFile`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#file-parameters-with-uploadfile) you can achieve your goal:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile

app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/example")
async def create_upload_file(
    file: UploadFile, transaction_id: str, organization_id: str
):
    file_name = organization_id + transaction_id
    with open(file_name, "wb") as out_file:
        contents = file.file.read()
        out_file.write(contents)
```

This will save the uploaded file in the cwd of your server with a name obtained by concatenating organization_id and transaction_id (bit it can easily be customized).

Comment: Hello Matteo firstly thank you for your answer. But when i do this i am getting error. The error was encoding error. But i find the answer. I will share it soon.

Comment: @SedatUnal I tried this code and was getting no error... Please include a traceback of your error. Also how are you calling this API (I used the swagger docs automatically provided by fastapi)?

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is:

```
@app.post("/example")
async def example(image: UploadFile = File(...), transaction_id: str = Form(...), organization_id: str = Form(...)):
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77605018/17865804) might also help with your task