# How to upload both Files and a List of dictionaries using Pydantic's BaseModel in FastAPI?

Tags: python, json, fastapi, multipartform-data, pydantic

I have the following code example:

```
from fastapi import File, UploadFile, Request, FastAPI, Depends
from typing import List
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import Optional

app = FastAPI()

class BaseBox(BaseModel):
    l: float=Field(...)
    t: float=Field(...)
    r: float=Field(...)
    b: float=Field(...)

class BaseInput(BaseModel):
    boxes: List[BaseBox] = Field(...)
    words: List[str] = Field(...)
    width: Optional[float] = Field(...)
    height: Optional[float] = Field(...)

@app.post("/submit")
def submit(
    base_input: BaseInput = Depends(),
    file: UploadFile = File(...),  # Add this line to accept a file
):

    return {
        "JSON Payload": base_input,
        "Filename": file.filename,
    }

@app.get("/")
def main(request: Request):
    return {"status":"alive"}
```

but some how I can not make it works. I use the interactive API docs, but I always get an error. Do you think I have to send 2 files instead?
I did also try with

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:8007/submit?width=10&height=10' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'file=@test.png;type=image/png' \
  -F 'boxes={
  "l": 0,
  "t": 0,
  "r": 0,
  "b": 0
}' \
  -F 'words=test,test2,tes3,test'
```

but I always get the error
`"POST /submit?width=10&height=10 HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity`.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: did you try without `base_input` or without `file`?  It may show which element can make problem.

Comment: You can't - you can't have both a JSON body and a UploadFile, since they use different mechanisms - one submits data as a Form fields and encoding type, while the other uses JSON as its content-type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add both file and JSON body in a FastAPI POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65504438/how-to-add-both-file-and-json-body-in-a-fastapi-post-request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown from the code you provided, you already had a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804), and that is where you should find the solution you are looking for in the end. Related answers can also be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71439821/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77279612/17865804).

But, let me explain what is wrong with the code in your example. You are submitting both Files and query data, or, at least, that is what seems you have been trying to achieve. Having a query parameter defined, for instance, as `str` or `int`, in an endpoint, or a Pydantic model along with using `Depends()` on a parameter in the endpoint to indicate that the fileds defined in the `BaseModel` are expected as query parameters, in both cases, it should work just fine. However, when you define a parameter as a `List`, e.g., `List[int]` or `List[str]`, either directly in the endpoint or in a `BaseModel`, you should [**define it explicitly with `Query`**](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/#query-parameter-list-multiple-values), as explained and demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71427592/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73982479/17865804). While Pydantic models did not allow the use of `Query` fields in the past, and one had to implement the query parameter-parsing in a separate dependency class, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70845425/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73067473/17865804), this has recently been changed, and hence, one could instead wrap the `Query()` in a `Field()` using a `BaseModel` class, as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75998823/17865804).

#### Working Example 1

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Query, Depends
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import Optional, List

app = FastAPI()


class Base(BaseModel):
    width: Optional[float] = Field (...)
    height: Optional[float] = Field (...)
    words: List[str] = Field (Query(...))  #  wrap the `Query()` in a `Field()` for `List` params
    

@app.get('/')
async def main(base: Base = Depends()):
    return base
```

In your example, you also seem to have a `List` query parameter that expects as a value a list of dictionary/JSON objects. That, however, **cannot** be achieved using query parameters. If you attempted defining such a parameter (e.g., `boxes: List[BaseBox] = Field (Query(...))`) in the working example above, you would come accross the following error when trying to run the FastAPI application:

> AssertionError: Param: `boxes` **can only be a request body**, using
> `Body()`

If you instead defined the parameter as `boxes: List[BaseBox] = Field (...)`, along with `file: UploadFile = File(...)` defined in the endpoint, as you have already been doing in your code, even though the application would start running as usual, when attempting to submit a request to that endpoint (through Swagger UI autodocs at `/docs`, for instance), you would receive a `422 Unprocessable Entity` error, with a message that has a similar meaning, saying that `Input should be a valid dictionary or object to extract fields from`.

That is because, in the first case, you can't have a query parameter expecting dictionary data (unless you followed the approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70840850/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73831142/17865804) for arbitrary query data, which you would need to parse on your own, and which I would not recommend doing), while, in the second case, the request body is sent encoded as `multipart/form-data` due to the `file: UploadFile = File(...)` field defined in the endpoint; however, sending both Form and JSON data together is not supported by the HTTP protocol (again, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804)).

If, however, you removed the `UploadFile` parameter from the endpoint, the request should go through successfully, as the request body would then be endoced as `application/json` (have a look at the `Content-Type` request header in Swagger UI when submitting the request). In that case, however, you should use a `POST` request—and hence, define your endpoint with `@app.post('/')`, for instance—not a `GET` one, as a request with `GET`/`HEAD` method shouldn't have a body ([Requests using `GET` method should **only** be used to request data; they shouldn't include data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET)).

#### Working Example 2

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Query, Depends
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import Optional, List

app = FastAPI()

class BaseBox(BaseModel):
    l: float = Field(...)
    t: float = Field(...)
    
class Base(BaseModel):
    width: Optional[float] = Field (...)
    height: Optional[float] = Field (...)
    words: List[str] = Field (Query(...))  #  wrap the `Query()` in a `Field()` for `List` params
    boxes: List[BaseBox] = Field (...)


@app.post('/')
async def main(base: Base = Depends()):
    return base
```

### Posting both File(s) and JSON body (including `List` of dictionaries)

If you still had to add **both** File(s) and JSON body in a FastAPI POST request, I would highly suggest having a look at **Methods 3 and 4** of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804). The examples provided below are based on those two approaches in the linked answer, and demonstrate how to post Files together with JSON data that also include lists of dictionaries, just like in your example. Please have a look at the linked answer for further details and examples in Python and JavaScript on how to test the approaches. In your case, you would need to separate query parameters from body fields, and have query parameters defined either in the endpoint (as explained in the linked answers provided earlier), or in separate Pydantic models, as demonstrated below.

#### Working Example 3 (based on Method 3 of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804))

In Swagger UI `/docs`, since `data` is a `Form` parameter and represented as a single field, you would need to pass the data for `Base` in that field as a dictionary, which will be submitted as `str` in the `data` `Form` parameter. Test example:

```
{"boxes": [{"l": 0,"t": 0,"r": 0,"b": 0}], "comments": ["foo", "bar"], "code": 0}
```

For further information on how to test this, see the linked answer above.

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, status, Form, UploadFile, File, Depends, Query
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, ValidationError
from fastapi.exceptions import HTTPException
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
from typing import Optional, List


app = FastAPI()


class BaseParams(BaseModel):
    width: Optional[float] = Field (...)
    height: Optional[float] = Field (...)
    words: List[str] = Field (Query(...))  #  wrap the `Query()` in a `Field()` for `List` params


class BaseBox(BaseModel):
    l: float=Field(...)
    t: float=Field(...)
    r: float=Field(...)
    b: float=Field(...)


class Base(BaseModel):
    boxes: List[BaseBox] = Field (...)
    comments: List[str] = Field (...)
    code: int = Field (...)
    

def checker(data: str = Form(...)):
    try:
        return Base.model_validate_json(data)
    except ValidationError as e:
        raise HTTPException(
            detail=jsonable_encoder(e.errors()),
            status_code=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
        )


@app.post("/submit")
def submit(
    base_params: BaseParams = Depends(),
    base: Base = Depends(checker),
    files: List[UploadFile] = File(...),
):
    return {
        "Params": base_params,
        "JSON Payload": base,
        "Filenames": [file.filename for file in files],
    }
```

#### Working Example 4 (based on Method 4 of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804))

This approach has the advantage of requiring less code to achieve the expected outcome, as well as the `Base` model is represented (with an automatically generated input example) in the request body section of Swagger UI `/docs`, resulting in a more clear view of the data and easier way of posting the data. Again, please have a look at the linked answer above for more details on this approach.

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Body, UploadFile, File, Depends, Query
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, model_validator
from typing import Optional, List
import json


app = FastAPI()


class BaseParams(BaseModel):
    width: Optional[float] = Field (...)
    height: Optional[float] = Field (...)
    words: List[str] = Field (Query(...))  #  wrap the `Query()` in a `Field()` for `List` params

    
class BaseBox(BaseModel):
    l: float=Field(...)
    t: float=Field(...)
    r: float=Field(...)
    b: float=Field(...)


class Base(BaseModel):
    boxes: List[BaseBox] = Field (...)
    comments: List[str] = Field (...)
    code: int = Field (...)

    @model_validator(mode="before")
    @classmethod
    def validate_to_json(cls, value):
        if isinstance(value, str):
            return cls(**json.loads(value))
        return value


@app.post("/submit")
def submit(
    base_params: BaseParams = Depends(),
    base: Base = Body(...),
    files: List[UploadFile] = File(...),
):
    return {
        "Params": base_params,
        "JSON Payload": base,
        "Filenames": [file.filename for file in files],
    }
```

Comment: I am sorry, I did not have the time to try it out. Today I try example 4 and it looks good to me. Thank you.