# How to validate a FastAPI GET parameter with Pydantic, without a model

Tags: get, fastapi, pydantic

I have a very simple FastAPI `GET` endpoint. It does not accept any request body - it only accepts a single, mandatory `GET` parameter. For example:

`/v1/app/end?foo=abcdef1234567890`

This `foo` parameter absolutely must conform to some regex. I've simplified the regex for the purposes of this question, but it's nothing crazy.

## When it worked

This was easy enough to do, and in fact, I had it working in Pydantic 1.9:

```py
# Works perfectly with Pydantic v1.9
from pydantic import constr

MY_REGEX = r"^[a-z0-9]{16}$"

@router.get(
    "/v1/app/end",
    response_model=src.schemas.foo.Bar,
)
def get_with_parameter(
    foo: constr(regex=MY_REGEX),
) -> src.schemas.foo.Bar:
```

---

## When it broke

Now, moving to Pydantic 2.5, I can no longer do this. Note that I have renamed `regex` to `pattern`, but it should still do the same thing.

```py
# Validation is completely ignored!
def get_with_parameter(
    foo: constr(pattern=MY_REGEX),
) -> src.schemas.foo.Bar:
```

Following the suggestions in the official documentation and source code does not work either:

```py
# Validation is completely ignored!
from typing_extensions import Annotated
from pydantic import StringConstraints

def get_with_parameter(
    foo: Annotated[str, StringConstraints(pattern=MY_REGEX)],
) -> src.schemas.foo.Bar:
```

---

## Glitchy fix

I found that I can make it work again, but only if I make it Optional, Final, or some other weird type, which I do not want to do:

```py
from typing import Optional, Final

# Validation works, but is now Optional
def get_with_parameter(
    foo: Optional[constr(pattern=MY_REGEX)],
) -> src.schemas.foo.Bar:


# Validation works, but is now Final
def get_with_parameter(
    foo: Final[constr(pattern=MY_REGEX)],
) -> src.schemas.foo.Bar:
```

--

**How can I get this to work like it used to?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a fix, which was to use the `Query` type from FastAPI

```py
from typing import Annotated
from fastapi import Query

@router.get(
    "/v1/app/end",
    response_model=src.schemas.foo.Bar,
)
def get_with_parameter(
    foo: Annotated[str, Query(pattern=MY_REGEX)]),
) -> src.schemas.foo.Bar:
```

Comment: Using [`Query`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations) type might be the most suited way. Also, one could enforce the length value in `Query` parameters, using `min_length` and `max_length` arguments. If you, or future readers, had to do this in a Pydantic model, or had query parameters expecting a list of values, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75998823/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77605018/17865804) might proved helpful. For using regex patterns in a `BaseModel`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71258131/17865804).

Comment: Excellent idea! I explored using the length, but I found that it didn't help either - the regex/pattern and length were all ignored, until I put them into a `Query`. And besides, my regex required other checks apart from length

Comment: @Chris - I see you're quite experienced with these kinds of questions. Can you please explain why you use `Field` in many of your answers and solutions? I'm pretty new to this, and am not sure of best practice - still just trying to get it working.